# How to generate the GraphQL client for a secured GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, ballerina

How can I generate the `auth` parameter using the `bal graphql` command? When I run `bal graphql --help`, I don't see any options. Do I need to manually modify the generated code?

I have generated the GraphQL client using the latest version of Ballerina and it creates a record named public type `ConnectionConfig` record. How can I set the authentication for the client using `tokenUrl`, `clientId` and `clientSecret` within this record?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the code generation supports only four types of authentication configurations:

1. No auth
2. API key config
3. Bearer-token/Basic Auth config
4. API key config & bearer-token/Basic Auth config

In this context, you need to add the `extensions` section in the GraphQL config file with the relevant tokens and headers. These values are used when generating the client. It is mandatory to configure the `schema` section with the web URL of the GraphQL schema, as shown below.

```yaml
schema: <The web URL of the GraphQL schema.>
documents:
   - <File path to the GraphQL document with the GraphQL queries & mutations>
extensions:
   endpoints:
      default:
         headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer token", "API_Header_Key1": "API_Header_Value1", "API_Header_Key2": "API_Header_Value2" }
```

At the moment, `OAuth2` grant configurations are not supported to be passed as parameters during code generation. It has to be included manually after the code generation. For more details, check this [example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/graphql-client-security-oauth2-password-grant-type/).